# HOw to merge two rows into one adding last column if the row's first and second columns are equal

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two rows like this:

```
a   b  val
2   3  43
2   3  32
```

I want output to be

```
a  b  val
2  3  75=(43+32)
```

I want tis operation to be applied to the whole table.

How can I do this using an sql query - probably in sqlite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just need a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT  a, b, SUM(val)
FROM    YourTable
GROUP BY
        a, b
```

Comment: yeah! I m new to SQL..just wondering how quick the answers are! thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You want an aggregation query:

```
select a, b, sum(val)
from t
group by a, b
```